expss package in R: Error in forderv & unused argument (reuseSorting = TRUE)
i just started using the expss package in R and i have a very basic error message which i can't fix.
I just want to create simple cross tables with percentages, like they did here: https://gdemin.github.io/expss/#Cross-tablulation_examples
This is my code:
library(expss)
data(mtcars)
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      mpg = "Miles/(US) gallon",
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      disp = "Displacement (cu.in.)",
                      hp = "Gross horsepower",
                      drat = "Rear axle ratio",
                      wt = "Weight (1000 lbs)",
                      qsec = "1/4 mile time",
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-engine" = 0,
                             "Straight engine" = 1),
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      gear = "Number of forward gears",
                      carb = "Number of carburetors"
)
cross_cpct(mtcars, cyl, list(total(), am, vs))


And this the (in english translated) error message i get:
Error in forderv(x, cols, sort = TRUE, retGrp = !physical, reuseSorting = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (reuseSorting = TRUE)

I would really appreciate some help! Thx

Welcome to SO! Your code works fine using expss 0.11.6. Could you check your package version?

@stefan Thank u for your answer :) I use expss 0.11.6 as well and it doesn't work for me

Hm. The error relates to a function from the data.table package. Perhaps check and update the version of data.table. Mine is 1.16.2.

I had a old version of data.table. i updated it. Now it works. Thx a lot stefan :)
